# wysihtlm5 form submit and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysihtml5

I'm having trouble implementing the wysihtlm5 editor using the wysihtml5-rails gem: https://github.com/NARKOZ/wysihtml5-rails

First of all, my html tags are not saved to the database. Then if the form submit fails, the text_area is only filled with plain text. How can i make sure, the html tags are sent to the server in the right way?

In the debug output i can see that the description is arriving in the controller without html tags:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fW5FMxr/sgNkLUowLT2E0UfIXtFbXvkOubPYM0GJm0I=",  "description"=>"sdfgsdfg"}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1"}
```

application.js:

```
//= require wysihtml5
//= require parser_rules/advanced
```

In my view:

```
<%= form_for @auction do |f| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="auction_days">Beschreibung</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div id="wysihtml5-toolbar" style="display: none;">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a data-wysihtml5-command="bold" title="CTRL+B" class="btn"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
              <a data-wysihtml5-command="italic" title="CTRL+I" class="btn"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
              <a data-wysihtml5-command="underline" title="CTRL+U" class="btn"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a> 
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h1" class="btn">H1</a>
              <a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h2" class="btn">H2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
             <a data-wysihtml5-command="insertUnorderedList" class="btn"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
             <a data-wysihtml5-command="insertOrderedList" class="btn"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
           </div>

           <a data-wysihtml5-command="createLink" class="btn"><i class="icon-link"></i> Link</a>

           <!--<a data-wysihtml5-action="change_view">switch to html view</a>-->
           <br /><br />
           <div data-wysihtml5-dialog="createLink" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-info input-xxlarge">
            <label><strong>Link einfügen:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" data-wysihtml5-dialog-field="href" value="http://" class="span3">

            <a data-wysihtml5-dialog-action="save" class="btn">OK</a> <a data-wysihtml5-dialog-action="cancel" class="btn">Abbrechen</a>
          </div>

        </div>
        <%= f.text_area :description, :id => 'wysihtml5-textarea', :label=>false, :class=>"input-xxlarge", :placeholder => "Beschreibung hier einfügen ..."  %>

        <script>              
          var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-textarea", {
            toolbar:      "wysihtml5-toolbar",
            parserRules:  "wysihtml5ParserRules"
          });
        </script>
      </div>

      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-success") do %>
         <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Send          
      <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

is the editor load properly? try inspect element in browser for the case when validation fail ,is because what you re saving is plain text, so it will just display plain text for you as well.

I saw there is a html view tag in the demo, maybe you try check whether it can be changed to html text or not.

Additionally: 
I personally recommend the plain 1 without gem.
https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg

or ckeditor or tinymce :D